# turtlebot_kinect_arm_calibration not compiling in fuerte

Tags: pcl, turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been struggling getting the Kinect arm calibration package to compile on Ubuntu 11.10 with Fuerte. I answered my first issue [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/33553/porting-from-eigen-2-to-eigen-3) which might need updating on the Turtlebot repo.

I'm still unable to resolve issues with:

turtlebot_kinect_arm_calibration/src/calibrate_kinect_checkerboard.cpp:317:5: error:
**‘estimateRigidTransformationSVD’ is not a member of ‘pcl’**

I believe the function ‘estimateRigidTransformationSVD’ is suppose to be in the [rigid_transforms.hpp](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.0.1/rigid__transforms_8hpp_source.html) file. I can't find that file anywhere on my computer, but that might be because I am using PCL binaries?

*rosmake pcl* and *rosmake pcl_ros* build without failure. I also installed PCL through *sudo apt-get install libpcl-all*. Not sure what else to try...

Additionally, there is an OpenCV linker issues when the above issue is commented out. I'd love some help in getting this working, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33563/turtlebot_kinect_arm_calibration-not-compiling-in-fuerte/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To followup on this old, unanswered question, I ended up figuring out how to port the code to Fuerte then Groovy, and update the depreciated PCL and OpenCV methods. My work for the ClamArm can be found here:
https://github.com/davetcoleman/clam_catkin/tree/master/src/clam_vision

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1